# A question about induction.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, induction

Are we allowed to perform induction only on set of natural numbers or can we also perform induction on say set of even integers?

Comment: Well, you should be a bit clearer about it, but sure.  So long as there is a clear notion of successor and such.

Comment: Yes, we can begin with $n=2$ and apply the step from $n$ to $n+2$ to show something for all even positive integers. Usually , negative numbers are not considered in an induction proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the strictest theoretic sense, no. Mathematical induction applies only to predicates taking an argument $n \in \Bbb{N}$ (i.e. a true/false statement that depends on an unknown $n \in \Bbb{N}$, e.g. "$n$ is even"). It states that, if we have a predicate $P(n)$, where $n \in \Bbb{N}$, such that $P(0)$ is true and $P(n) \implies P(n + 1)$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$, then $P(n)$ is true for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$.

In practice, this principle is far more flexible. If we want to prove $Q(n)$ for all $n \ge 7$, we can simply let $P(n)$ be $Q(n + 7)$ and apply induction as above. If we want to prove $Q(n)$ for positive even integers, that's easy too: let $P(n)$ be $Q(2n + 2)$, then use induction.

We could even induct over all the integers. If we wish to prove $Q(n)$ for all $n \in \Bbb{Z}$, we let $P(n)$ be $Q(n)$ and $P'(n)$ be $Q(-n)$ for $n \in \Bbb{N}$. We can then prove $P(n)$ and $P'(n)$ for all $n$ using induction, and that will prove $Q(n)$ for all $n \in \Bbb{Z}$. Induction over all even integers would work similarly.

What sets can't you use induction on? Essentially, our predicates need to be indexed by a [well-ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order), and preferably order-isomorphic to $\Bbb{N}$ (unless you use the more complex [transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction)). Inducting over the real numbers wouldn't work so well, because there is no "next" real number, so the induction step is kinda meaningless.

I hope that helps.

Comment: so could we perform induction on say set of primes

Comment: Yep, the set of primes would be perfectly fine. In practical terms, that could be a little tricky to pull off, as the next prime tends to have little to do with the previous prime, but there's nothing wrong with that in theory.